# How to avoid multiple inserting same data when refresh the Laravel App Page

Tags: php, laravel

How to prevent multiple time inserting same data in Database when refresh the Laravel Web Application User Insert Page. I generate Unique User Id. but some times my Internet connection is lost and try to connect. that data inserted twice with same user id. how to avoid it.

```
public function savenewusers(Request $request){

    $data=$_POST;   

    $usersid = Auth::user()->id;

    $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required','email'=>'required','role'=>'required','password'=>'required','useraddress'=>'required','district'=>'required']);   

    $userslastcount=User::OrderBy('id','DESC')->first();

    if(count($userslastcount) > 0){
    $uniqid=$userslastcount->uniqueid+1;
    $userid="EF000".$uniqid;    
    } else {
    $uniqid=1;
    $userid="EF000".$uniqid;
    }  

    if(isset($data['managerid'])){
    $managerid=$data['managerid'];      
    } else {
    $managerid="";      
    }

    $password=Hash::make($request->password);

    $createUsers=User::create(['name'=>$data['name'],'email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$password]);

    $updateUsers=User::Where('id',$createUsers->id)->update(['userid'=>$userid,'officemobileno'=>$data['officemobileno'],'useraddress'=>$data['useraddress'],'district'=>$data['district'],'personalmobileno'=>$data['personalmobileno'],'personalemail'=>$data['personalemail'],'role'=>$data['role'],'managerid'=>$managerid,'uniqueid'=>$uniqid,'enable'=>1]);

    alert()->success('User Created Successfully.', 'Success!'); 

    return redirect('users');       


    }
```

Comment: Isn't the user id marked as unique?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must follow anyone of column should be unique email or username.

Can you use route binding validation like this:

```
public function saveNewUsers(UserValidationRequest $request)
{

}
```

And then you have to create validation request file.
use this command :

```
php artisan make:request UserValidationRequest
```

Validation file: `UserValidationRequest.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class UserValidationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `firstOrCreate`.

```
$user = User::firstOrCreate(['name'=>$data['name'],'email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$password]);

if ($user->wasRecentlyCreated) {

}
```